# React - remove nested array item using setState function call

Tags: reactjs, filter, setstate

I am trying to remove a (semi) deeply nested item from an array using setState but it doesn't seem to be working. My state is structured as follows:

```
state = {
  currentSeries: null,
  currentRowIndex: null,
  rows: [
    {
      id: shortid.generate(),
      nodes: [], 
      series: [], // array with item I want to remove
    },
  ],
};
```

and my remove item call:

```
onRemoveModelElementClick = (rowId, modelElementId) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const index = prevState.rows.findIndex(x => x.id === rowId);
    const series = prevState.rows[index].series.filter(s => s.id !== modelElementId);
    return series;
  });
};
```

I tried spreading the remaining state is several ways but it does not seem to update properly. I the rowId and modelElementId are correct and I can verify they do filter the correct item out. I am just having trouble on what to return. I know it is something simple but for the life of me I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to make things are bit easier to digest. You can then write it like so:

```
onRemoveModelElementClick = (rowId, modelElementId) => {
  const updatedRowsState = this.state.rows.map(row => {
    // this is not the row you're looking for so return the original row
    if (row.id !== rowId) {
      return row;
    }

    const filteredSeries = row.series.filter(s => s.id !== modelElementId);
    return {
      // spread properties (id, node, series)
      ...row,
      // overwrite series with item filtered out
      series: filteredSeries,
    };
  });

  // since rest of the state doesn't change, we only need to update rows property
  this.setState('rows', updatedRowsState);
}
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is a great idea. What you wrote does not work out of the box but it got me to a solution so I'm accepting it. I will add an answer for what I did to get it to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is how your code uses `setState`. The `setState` function must return an object. Assuming your filtering functions are correct as you describe, return an object to update the state:

```
return { series };
```

[setState documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get it working in case it can help someone else:

```
onRemoveModelElementClick = (rowId, modelElementId) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const updatedRowState = prevState.rows.map((row) => {
      if (row.id !== rowId) {
        return row;
      }

      const filteredSeries = row.series.filter(s => s.id !== modelElementId);
      return {
        ...row,
        series: filteredSeries,
      };
    });
    return {
      rows: updatedRowState,
    };
  });
};
```

All credit to Dom for the great idea and logic!