# Delete an array item from an array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an array like this:
subzones:{name , [rows]}
Here rows is an array .  I want to delete rows array from subzones array.

This is what i did:

```
deleteRows = (idx, sub_idx) => {
    // console.log(idx)
    var taskl = this.state.subzones
    var sub_taskl = this.state.subzones[idx].rows
    sub_taskl.splice(sub_idx, 1);
    taskl[idx].rows = sub_taskl
    this.setState({
        subzones: taskl
    });
    console.log("deleteRows", this.state.subzones)
};
```

But its not working . Any Suggestions?

Comment: please provide expected input and output with example. Question is not clear

Comment: There is a subzone array .Inside that rows field is there which is an array which i have to remove when clicking on delete button

Comment: Do you want to delete all rows from all subzone ?

Comment: No a particular row which i am clicking on that paricular row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - remove nested array item using setState function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600829/react-remove-nested-array-item-using-setstate-function-call)